# Macro to avoid duplicate case value

Tags: c, macros

I am using a switch expression in C in order to evaluate the errno variable. According to the man page for `send()`:

**EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK**

> ```
> The socket is marked nonblocking and the requested operation would block.
> POSIX.1-2001 allows either error to be returned for this case,and does not
> require these constants to have the same value, so a portable application
> should check for both possibilities.
> ```

Since my application must be portable, I have to do:

```
switch (errno):
  case EWOULDBLOCK:
  case EAGAIN:
    //do whatever
    break;
  case EINTR:
    //...
```

The problem is that for some platforms, EWOULDBLOCK and EAGAIN do have the same value, so when compiling I get:

> ```
>  connection.cxx:190:5: error: duplicate case value
>  case EWOULDBLOCK:
>  ^
>  connection.cxx:189:5: error: previously used here
>  case EAGAIN:
>  ^
> ```

So I thought I could use a macro macro that depending on whether EWOULDBLOCK and EAGAIN have the same value or not for the platform adds that line to the code or omits it.

Any idea on how to write that macro?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like:

```
 #if EAGAIN != EWOULDBLOCK
      case EAGAIN:
 #endif
      case EWOULDBLOCK:
```

edit: however if you're going to have many switch switch statements, a macro would be better than the conditional compilation.  Something like:

```
 #if EAGAIN == EWOULDBLOCK
 #define MY_AGAIN EAGAIN
 #else
 #define MYAGAIN EAGAIN: case EWOULDBLOCK
 #endif
```

Then to use it:

```
 case MY_AGAIN:
```

You'll see that the colon is not part of the macro at the point where it is called:

```
 case ---->MACRO GOES HERE<-----:
```

however in the second case, when expanded in the context of the original surrounding text:

```
 case EAGAIN: case EWOULDBLOCK:
```

that would be real ugly if it were written explicitly within your switch statement but is perfectly legal C code.

Comment: I was trying to avoid this solution in the event that `EAGAIN` and `EWOULDBLOCK` were constants that could not be evaluated by the preprocessor. I don't think the UNIX spec says that the `errno` constants must be evaluatable by the preprocessor, even though this is probably the case on most systems.

Comment: Sometimes errno is a macro that evaluates to a function call rather than a variable.  That permits one to use threads in which there is a separate per-thread value that is not overwritten by system calls from other threads.

Comment: Could EAGAIN and friends be enums?  Those would not be accessible to the preprocessor, however you could do "#define myAgain EAGAIN, #define myWouldBLock EWOULDBLOCK", then use the my* constants everywhere you would otherwise use the E* ones.

Comment: I don't see what that has to do with anything? If `EWOULDBLOCK` cannot be evaluated by the preprocessor then `#if EAGAIN == EWOULDBLOCK` won't work correctly. (It may actually silently fail)

Comment: @nneonneo POSIX specifies: *The following macro names identify the possible error numbers* and *All object-like macros listed as expanding to integer constant expressions shall additionally be suitable for use in #if preprocessing directives.* The C standard specifies: *The macros [...] expand to integer constant expressions with type int [...] which are suitable for use in #if preprocessing directives.*

Answer (score 5):

Don't use a `switch`, then; just use

```
if(errno == EWOULDBLOCK || errno == EAGAIN) {
    ...
}
```

The compiler of course will happily optimize this to a single test if `EWOULDBLOCK` is in fact equal to `EAGAIN`.

Comment: While your code is correct, it's slower and uses more space than either of the macros I provide.  switch/case statements are often implemented as jump tables, which are quite compact and fast.  That doesn't always matter but sometimes it does.

Comment: @MichaelCrawford: you're checking the errno off the back of a system call, a call that usually takes on the order of thousands to hundreds of thousands of cycles to execute, and you're haggling over (at most) 1-2 machine cycles on the errno-checking end? And you don't trust that the compiler can see that the `if` test is transparently just checking a simple value and optimize that?

Comment: The size of the code - that is, the number of machine instructions - may be more important than the amount of time it takes to run the instructions.  That would be the case for very small embedded targets.  In a large project, taking care to keep code size small can reduce backing store paging, as well as code cache thrashing.

Comment: @MichaelCrawford: I have just compiled a program for ARM which uses a `switch`, and one that uses an `if` chain. The `if` chain comes out one instruction shorter (ARM uses constant-size opcodes). Obviously not a big deal either way, but it's a clear refutation of what you've just claimed.

Comment: If your code was an if chain of errno values, quite likely the optimizer replaced it with a jump table, which is what a switch statement also tries to use.

Comment: I have actual experience of a mask error in an embedded ARM core, that I was able to work around by replacing one instruction with two, that slowed down my code by ten percent.  Of course those two instructions were in the innermost of a bunch of nested loops, in this case an AES encryptor.

Comment: @MichaelCrawford: `errno` values are so spread out that the compiler has chosen *not* to use a jump table for either of my programs. This makes sense: a jump table would only increase bloat if most of the entries were absent.

Comment: @MichaelCrawford: and what are you saying with the 10% example? then the if-chain could be 10% faster than a `switch`?

Comment: I'm saying that the overall speed of an entire program can be significantly impacted by one single machine instruction.

Comment: @MichaelCrawford: Not when a system call is involved in the loop.